# Free Compiler for Windows on x86_64

Tags: c, windows, compiler-construction, 64-bit

I'm writing a compiler which uses C as an intermediate code which is (Currently) passed out to MinGW for compilation into an EXE file.

I'm looking for an x64 compiler that I can include in my releases, so that users of my application can get around Win64's "Windows on Windows" system to access native resources. MinGW allows me to distribute the compiler, but it doesn't seem to support generation of 64 bit binaries.

Thanks in advance :)

Billy3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VisualStudio Express

Comment: I don't think the EULA for Visual Studio (even Express) allows you to redistribute the compiler.

Comment: Yeah.. users will have to download it. Luckily I'm not charging for this app :P

Answer (score 8):

Looks like this might be what you're after:

> The [mingw-w64 project](http://mingw-w64.org) is a complete
>   runtime environment for gcc to support
>   binaries native to Windows 64-bit and
>   32-bit operating systems.

Comment: Had some difficulty with it.. seems to be based on an old copy of GCC.  I'll keep it in mind. +1

Comment: Since the mingw-w64 project on sourceforge.net is moving to mingw-w64.org i suggest to use [mingw-w64.org](http://mingw-w64.org)

Comment: @poqdavid: Done, I'm not sure why the edit was rolled back, seems apt to me.

Comment: @caf Well i hope the comment it's clear for users who come and look at this

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Tiny C Compiler](http://bellard.org/tcc/), which is [available under the LGPL](http://www.mail-archive.com/tinycc-devel@nongnu.org/msg01116.html), and which supports x86-64.  It's also approaching "full ISOC99 compliance."

Comment: It supports running on x86-64. but not generation of x86-64 binaries. Nice project though ... might use this instead of MinGW for the 32 bit version. MinGW is huge.

Comment: I had never tried running or creating x86-64 binaries with it, I was just repeating their (very sparse) documentation -- that's kind of a bummer :/

Comment: Looking at it some more, it supports x86-64 only on UNIX architectures. Thanks anyway though :) I've changed to this for the i386 architecture... it's a lot nicer to be able to embed the compiler instead of relying on the HUGE! MinGW.

Thank you :)